NestJS microservice using Redis Pub/Sub does not receive any messages
I'm encountering a random issue when using Redis Pub/Sub. I have 2 services: Gateway Service and Task Service. They can communicate with each other. However, after a few hours, the Task Service stops receiving any messages from the Gateway Service without any errors on the server
I've used psubscribe get_task to listen to the channel and can see the full message, but the Task Service is unable to receive it.
Here is the configuration:
RedisConfig
export const RedisConfig = {
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  port: +process.env.REDIS_PORT,
  password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
  family: 4, // 4 (IPv4) or 6 (IPv6)
  db: 0,
  retryAttempts: 20,
  retryDelay: 2000,
  connectTimeout: 3000,
  retryStrategy: function (times: number) {
    console.log('Number of retries to connect: ', times);
    return Math.min(times * 50, 2000);
  },
};

Gateway Service
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(GatewayModule);
  const port = 8081;
  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.REDIS,
    options: {
      name: 'Gateway',
      ...RedisConfig,
    },
  });
  await app.startAllMicroservices();
  await app.listen(port).then(() => {
    console.log(`Gateway running on port ${port}`);
  });
}
bootstrap();

Task Service
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(TaskModule, {
    transport: Transport.REDIS,
    options: {
      name: 'Task',
      ...RedisConfig,
    },
  });

  await app.listen().then(() => {
    console.log(`Task service is running`);
  });
}
bootstrap();

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? I can't seem to find one. It works after I restart the server
Thank you!!
